# another term/phrase for 'living in somebody else's shoes'

Tags: word-choice, phrases, expressions, phrase-requests

Describing a situation - There are three 3 people

**A, B and C:**

A - the most rich; successful

B - somewhat successful; ok

C - Dirt poor

Now A says to B, *"you are poor because you didn't do the right things, make right decisions"*

B, like most middle class, feels a bit envious and, at the same time, guilty, as he knows there are lot of people like who are poor, like C.

So B is trying to defend his life choices and giving example of C while stating that it's not easy to question another's life choices because you don't know what she/he went through.

One way I could put is *"living in C's shoes or a third-party shoes"* but is there any other synonym or phrase which will convey without using this overused cliche?

I did cycle through the phrases **put oneself in another shoes** or **see through someone else's eyes** or even **walk a mile in other shoes** or even **You should trade places with X** but each of them sound much more cliche and overused than the next. Also for people who aren't native english speakers many a times these terms lose their meaning.

I am looking for something which is more direct but at the same time more sensitive too, not being harsh.

Comment: "Walk a mile in the other person's shoes" is probably the most idiomatic version of the saying.  But there are dozens of variations on this.  Another common sentiment is "You should trade places with X".

Comment: @hank I actually saw/searched through the phrases 'put oneself in another shoes' or 'see through someone else's eyes' or even 'walk a mile in other shoes' or even 'You should trade places with X' but each of them sound much more cliche and overused than the next.

Comment: @Hank edited my query and added as you asked.

Comment: Let's see -- you're asking for a cliche, but you don't want it to be cliched??

Comment: @HotLicks confusedly I am. The thing is it doesn't need to be cliche, it needs to be something which is more straighter. Wish I could express myself better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for someone to *feel empathy for the other person*

> Empathy: the action of understanding, being aware of, being sensitive
> to, and vicariously experiencing the feelings, thoughts, and
> experience of another of either the past or present without having the
> feelings, thoughts, and experience fully communicated in an
> objectively explicit manner
>
> Empathize: understand and share the feelings of another.

Via Merriam-Webster

*You should empathize with person C, he's a regular person just like you and me! He's just having a tough time.*

Comment: I *think* that's the closest I would be able to get to it, thanx.

Answer (score -1):

Something also like, "don't judge a book by its cover" gives the same meaning.

Comment: Can you expand upon why you t think this is the right answer?